# Can't get all the links connected to a hashtag from a lazy loading webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've created a script in python together with selenium to scroll to the bottom of a lazy-loading webpage and parse the content from there. I'm trying to get all the links connected to a hashtag from instagram. There are around 475 results out there but my current attempt fetches me only 38.

The script I've created can scroll to the bottom of that page but I still get 38 results out of some 475 results.

[Link to that webpage](https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/baltimorepizza/)

I've tried so far with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

tag = '#baltimorepizza'

hash_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{}/'

def scroll_to_get_more():
    check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")

    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        try:
            wait.until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  > check_height)
            check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;") 
        except TimeoutException:
             break

def get_links(tag):
    driver.get(hash_url.format(tag.strip("#").lower()))
    scroll_to_get_more()
    total_links = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.kIKUG > a')))]
    print("Total link scraped:",len(total_links))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    get_links(tag)
    driver.quit()
```

***How can I get all the links connected to that specific hashtag from instagram?***

Comment: are the links loading before you execute findElement post scroll?

Comment: I am getting 437 links while adding the links during scrolling.However I can't reach 475 links while doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as @KunduK, I can only gather 437, so I am wondering if this is the correct number, maybe you need to login to see the remaining ones..?

You are only getting ~38 because the page does not render the entire code in the DOM at one. So even if you scrolled, you queried the data but it is not all accessible, only when you scroll back to it (images in view).

Solution here will get the data while scrolling.
We will scroll at the bottom first and ensure all query was made to load the images using your method `scroll_to_get_more`.

Then we will start **scraping** from the top to bottom, so we need to scroll all the way back to the top using:

```
def scroll_to_header():
    el = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("header")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", el)
```

Your `get_links` method will now look like this:

```
def get_links(tag):
    driver.get(hash_url.format(tag.strip("#").lower()))
    scroll_to_get_more()
    scroll_to_header()
    total_links = []
    current_len = 0
    new_len = -1
    while current_len != new_len:
        current_len = len(total_links)
        try:
            links = []
            elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.Nnq7C.weEfm [href]')))
            for el in elements:
                if el.get_attribute('href') not in total_links:
                    links.append(el.get_attribute('href'))
            total_links.extend(links)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            continue
        if len(elements):
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", el)
        new_len = len(total_links)

    print("Total link scraped:", len(total_links))
```

Basically, after every query we are scrolling to the last element, which will load in the DOM the next images.

Also, I was thinking that your scroll method was the reason I was getting 437 (scrolling and missing elements). So I have implemented a new method, that use the spinner as the element to scroll, instead of the height of the page. Both are valid, but I think this one is faster (see result below):

```
def scroll_to_get_more():
    while True:
        try:
            spinner = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.By4nA')
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", spinner)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            continue
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
```

**Output with scrolling method above:**

```
Total link scraped: 437
Query took: 23.520002755
```

**Output with your scrolling method:**

```
Total link scraped: 437
Query took: 42.685470925
```

Main reason for the time difference is that you will always sleep 10 seconds once the page does not need to scroll anymore.